# Using BufferedWriter to write data into a .txt file, if the application is force-closed, any data stored to .txt files do not save?

Tags: java, text, bufferedwriter

This is the code I am using:

```
    public static void log(String directory, String name, String input) throws IOException {
    File path = new File(directory);
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(directory + "/" + name + ".txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);         
    bw.write(input);
    bw.close();
}
```

I have this application logging to many different .txt files while it is running. To my understanding, once the text file is "opened" by using this log method, it is occupied until the program is shut down. And when it is force closed for some reason (like shutting down my PC or closing it through task manager), it will not save any data that was written while it was opening. Is there any way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: `flush` the writer - which `close` will do. Your code is rather inefficient as opening and closing the file is an expensive operation. You also run the risk of leaving the file "open" if something goes wrong - consider using a `try-with-resources` block instead.  A slightly better solution might be to use a producer/consumer approach, where the messages are placed in a queue and then, on a separate thread, you write them out to the file.  This way you could open the file when there are new messages the queue, write/flush until the queue is empty, then close the file and wait for more

Comment: "IF" the JVM is forcefully terminated "while" a write operation is in progress, then no, I doubt there is anyway to you could fix the issue - it's a risk you'll need to take.  All of this raises questions over why you're not using the inbuilt logging API or log4j which will do all this for you anyway

Comment: `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());` is irrelevant, just use `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);`

Answer (score 0):

> To my understanding, once the text file is "opened" by using this log method, it is occupied until the program is shut down.

No. It is closed when you call `close()`.

> And when it is force closed for some reason (like shutting down my PC or closing it through task manager), it will not save any data that was written while it was opening.

The data will be flushed when you call close.

> Is there any way to solve this?

There is nothing to solve.

Comment: I think it was happening because the FileWriter was never closed

Comment: It was closed in the code you posted, by `bw.close()`. If that wasn't the real code, your question is futile.